# Apache not parsing files? Just sending downloads

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm just trying to setup some simple things. I put an index.php file in my documentroot. index.html works just fine (sends a webpage). If I try index.php, it assumes I'm trying to download it. How do I know if php is working on apache? Where should I look?

Comment: What system are you running this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will usually happen if you haven't added a handler to tell apache what to do with .php files.  In your apache configuration file, you should have a line like:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

which actually loads the module,  Then you'll need something like

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

To actually associate php files.  Additionally, you can add:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

which will treat index.php the same as index.html.